# Avoiding memory leaks within Angular components

Tags: angular

At angular application, I used Subscription type to capture(add) all my subscriptions. Subscription type has add method. At component's ngDestroy method, unsubscribe() all my subscriptions instead of using async pipe at html template. Is any problem for that approach?

Comment: The rule of thumb is - minimize your subscriptions inside your component (use async pipe as much as possible instead) - but if you subscribe, always unsubscribe. So you’re okay with unsubbing in destroy..

Comment: I don't want to use async pipes at all in the html template. The global Subscription instance has an add method and I can add all my subscriptions as children. And at ngDestroy, I can unsubscribe(). What is the downside of that approach compared to async pipe at html template.

Comment: In general, using the async pipe results in much cleaner (and less) code in your component with the added bonus that Angular will manage that subscription for you. But again, subscribing a lot in your components is a bit of a code smell anyway - it probably means that your not using rxjs operators correctly - which in turn can cause race conditions in your code.

Comment: I feel other way around. Html template is for html and css and not for code.  People forget to unsubscribe that is why async pipe came at later version.

Comment: All the previous points are valid I'd like to add that you don't necessarily have to unsubscribe from http client calls as each request is completed after the value is emitted. For everything else yeah async pipe (as much as possible) and the standard `destroy$` handler with `takeUntil`

Comment: @ttacompu - you are free to choose whatever solution you feel comfortable with of course. But you asked for opinions on this topic and you’ll probably find that once you start working on larger apps in larger teams, you’ll see the advantages :-)